# ionic avoid view title flickering on Android

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to do tab content page with the "standard" way as suggested by the ionic template example.

However, I found that when switching between tabs in Android, the view-title will flickering. You will not see the flickering on iOS or desktop browser. However, if you toggle device mode in Chrome to android devices, you will see the flickering.

How can I overcome it?

menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/tab/content1">
          Tab 1 Content 1
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Tab.html

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">

  <ion-tab title="Content1" href="#/app/tab/content1">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-Content"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Content2" href="#/app/tab/content2">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-Content2"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

content1.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Bookmarks">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

content2.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Bookmarks">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: May or may not be related to the flickering, however while working with similar solutions for Androids I've found that installing the Android Crosswalk project does help you with performance and consistency issues across all Android devices. [crosswalk homepage](https://crosswalk-project.org/) and [how to install](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/). The only downside is that your android .apk will increase by an approximate of 25mb

Comment: @AndersRehn Thanks for your comment. I don't think crosswalk will help much as I am seeing the flickering on chrome browser both on android and desktop (android device mode).

Comment: Might be a long shot but I found [this thread](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-view-transition-flickering/27441), perhaps the suggestions there might help, unless you have already tried this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks you to @AndresRehn for sharing the link (http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-view-transition-flickering/27441). The title flickering issue on android can be easily solved via adding the following into your CSS.

```
/*
    CSS styles to eliminate the annoying flickering header when changing tabs in an Ionic app on Android:
    http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/flickering-when-navigating-via-tabs-on-android/27281/2
*/
.platform-android .header-item.title {
    transition-duration: 0ms;
}
.platform-android .header-item.buttons {
    transition-duration: 0ms;
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely a life saver! Thank you! It was an obvious problem, just wondering why doesn't Ionic team see this problem???!

Comment: Anyone have a solution for Ionic 3.9.2?